# Pages whose titles differ by only one letter (selling designed alphabet letters) are not ranking well in search engines

Tags: seo, title

I am working on SEO for a client who has 15,000 products She sells Letters A-Z for home decoration. Each Product is different in some way than the other. Each product page title starts with the word {Letter} and {A-Z}. Our issues is her website is not ranking well on google search engine.

My main question is: 
Would seo improve if we put design # on the end of the title. Here is what I what mean.

Title Now:

> Letter A

Changed Title To:

> Letter A Design #1234

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would reduce the number of pages.

Imagine you have:

```
www.example.com/products/letterstyle1/a.php
www.example.com/products/letterstyle1/b.php
www.example.com/products/letterstyle1/c.php
www.example.com/products/letterstyle1/d.php
...
www.example.com/products/letterstyle2/a.php
www.example.com/products/letterstyle2/b.php
www.example.com/products/letterstyle2/c.php
www.example.com/products/letterstyle2/d.php
...
```

- I would redirect `www.example.com/products/letterstyle1/a.php` (`b.php`, `c.php`, etc) to `www.example.com/products/letterstyle1.php` (*)
- I would redirect `www.example.com/products/letterstyle2/a.php` (`b.php`, `c.php` etc) to `www.example.com/products/letterstyle2.php`
  ...

You'll end up with 577 (ish) product pages instead of 15000.

On those product pages, you can still show pictures of all A-Z letters in that style. Add the option to add the letters your visitors want to buy in that style to their shopping cart on that page.
Add a description of the style on each of your new product pages.

(*) I'd actually use a more descriptive filename than `letterstyle1.php`.

Comment: Thank you WebPro Sam. One quick question is this something the customer should be able to see or this more internal website structure. What I mean is.. if the customer goes on the homepage should there be a nested category of letterstyle{N} or is this just for seo structure? Where the customer does not have the option to click on a nested category?